# ocaml type missmatch unit vs list

Tags: ocaml, typechecking

For this signature

```
val chooser: string list * string list -> string list
```

and this implementation

```
 let rec chooser (inputList, trueList) = match inputList with
      [] -> []
    | iH::iT -> if (List.hd trueList)="True" 
        then iH::(chooser iT List.tl trueList)
```

I am getting the following error:

Error: This variant expression is expected to have type unit 
The constructor :: does not belong to unit

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `if ... then` with no `else` has to be `unit`, because the value will be `()` (the value of type `unit`) when the expression is false.

In other words, you need an `else` part for your `if` to get the type you want. What should the value be when the comparison is false?

Comment: You can't skip cases in a functional setting. Expressions have values all the time, it's just a question of what the value is! Example expression: `let y = if x < 5 then x + 1 else x`. You could say this "skips" the case where x >= 5. But it always has a value.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jeffrey! I had to add recursion with the tail too for the false case. It worked :)

Answer (score 1):

the `else` part is not explicitly defined - so when the condition is not statisfied, the else part is () (that is the unit). 
The compiler typechecks `iH::(chooser iT List.tl trueList)` as `unit` which is cannot be the case:

```
 if cond
    then A
    else B
```

`A` and `B` have the same types.

Comment: how to tell the REPL if it is false continue ?